# GitAhead - Unable to figure out how to squash commits

Tags: gitahead

I am using the latest GitAhead version and unable to figure out how to squash commits in my branch. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been merged Feb 11, 2020 and the last version has been released 27 Dec, 2019.

https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/pull/214

I don't know when the next release is going to air but since it has been merged into the master, I think this feature will be part of the next release.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I've been waiting for this.